# Sending test message from JAVASCRIPT to python

Tags: javascript, python

Sorry for the noob questions, i'm new on it.
I have a python server, and client and it's working.
There are :

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(1)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))

            data = str(data).upper()
            print ("sending: " + str(data))
            conn.send(data.encode())

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

and client

```
import socket

def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000

        mySocket = socket.socket()
        mySocket.connect((host,port))

        message = input(" -> ")

        while message != 'q':
                mySocket.send(message.encode())
                data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()

                print ('Received from server: ' + data)

                message = input(" -> ")

        mySocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main(
```

But when i want to make the same client but via JAVASCRIPT, i don's see this messages on server. Could someone please explain why?
There is my html file

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>  
    <script type="application/javascript">
        var ws;

        function init() {
            var servermsg = document.getElementById("servermsg");
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000/");
            ws.onopen = function(){
                servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Server connected";
            };
            ws.onmessage = function(e){
                servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br><< Recieved data: " + e.data;
            };
            ws.onclose = function(){
                servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Server disconnected";
            };
        }
        function postmsg(){
            var text = document.getElementById("message").value;
            ws.send(text);
            servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>>> Data sent: " + text;
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <form action="" onSubmit="postmsg();return false;">
        <input type="text" name="message" value="" id="message">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="servermsg"><h1>Message log:</h1></div>
</body>
```

Thank you everyone for the help

Comment: Possibly a security feature on your browser.

Comment: You should know that a websocket is not a nornal TCP socket, it is an HTTP initilized special protocol running over TCP.

Comment: Oh... so I must use websocket on this case?